# Is there a way to detect if there is a power management issue with an android phone?

Tags: battery, charging, battery-life, hardware, samsung-galaxy-note-4

## Is there a way to detect if there is a power management issue with an android phone?

**I'm rooted on KitKat if that helps.**

The phone in question is  a galaxy note 4 if it makes a difference.

The symptoms I have are new batteries purchased for the phone going from 40% to dead in a matter of seconds. Recently the phone refuses to charge more than 70% even on a new battery.  I'm assuming these are signs of some kind of power management failure.

I'm willing to install any suggested apps if that will help to determine the cause.

Comment: My first hunch would be to calibrate the battery: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blogspot.superthomaslab.batterycalibration&hl=en
it could be possible that when you are at 70% you are actually at 100%. 
After calibration, we'd hope to see a more linear decline of battery.

Comment: Wow, that might actually be my issue. I'll try to confirm this either today or tomorrow. If it works please make this an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Afraid you're following [a myth](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-engineer-debunks-myth-wiping-battery-stats-does-not-improve-battery-life/). All what the app does is deleting the `batterystats.bin` file (read the app desc). That file only holds stats on battery usage of apps (i.e. which app used how much battery) – ***NOT*** on the battery itself. Everything else (charging up to 100% and/or letting the battery drain to below 10%) can be done without an app. Though the problem here is the battery won't even charge up beyond 70%, as the question text says.